# Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor'

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am constantly running into the error listed below.

The Model should feed the form with 3 List<Food/Drink/Trick> each Food,Drink,Trick being a separate class. It is fetched from DB and works.

View should list names of each Food,Drink,Trick attribute name.

Food and Drink is singleselect. Trick is multiselect. Whatever is selected should be passed on the object Created.

My trouble is with the th:field="*{tricks}".

Thank you very much for a reply.

````
  public String createNewFoxGet(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String name) {

    if (name == null) {
      name = "";
    }

    model.addAttribute("fox", new Fox());

    model.addAttribute("tricksAll", trickService.getAllTrickTypes());
    model.addAttribute("drinkAll", drinkService.getAllDrinkTypes());
    model.addAttribute("foodAll", foodService.getAllFoodTypes());
    model.addAttribute("name", name);

    return "createnewfox";
  }
-----------------
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createnewfox}" th:object="${fox}" method="post">
  <p>New Fox</p>
<div class="form-group-name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="match with signup name" th:field="*{name}" minlength="2">
</div>

  <label for="favouriteFood">Favourite food:</label>
  <select name="favouriteFood" id="favouriteFood">
    <option th:each="element:${foodAll}" th:value="${element}" th:field="*{food}"
            th:text="${element.getName()}"></option>
  </select>

  <label for="favouriteDrink">Favourite drink:</label>
  <select name="favouriteDrink" id="favouriteDrink">
    <option th:each="element:${drinkAll}" th:value="${element}" th:field="*{drink}"
            th:text="${element.getName()}"></option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <label for="foxTricks">Fox tricks:</label>
  <select name="foxTricks" id="foxTricks" multiple>
    <option th:each="element:${tricksAll}" th:value="${element}" th:field="*{tricks}"
            th:text="${element.getName()}"></option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple tricks.</p>
  <br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GO!</button>

</form>
-----------------------------

An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/createnewfox.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/createnewfox.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor' (template: "createnewfox" - line 47, col 69)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringOptionFieldTagProcessor' (template: "createnewfox" - line 47, col 69)

Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Trick(id=1'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Trick(id=1"```
````

Comment: `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Trick(id=1'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Trick(id=1"`

Comment: It must be due to your data. Somehow "Trick(id=1" is being passed where its expecting a Number. What's on your line 47 on the createnewfox.html ?

Comment: line 47 is : <option th:each="element:${tricksAll}" th:value="${element}" th:field="*{tricks}" and the error points to the th:field

Comment: In line 47 maybe instead of th:value="${element}" it should be something like th:value="${element.getId()}". Like so you pass only the id (Long Type) and not the all object converted as a String.

Answer (score 0):

this one is solved. The issue was that the name="foxTricks" in select did not match to the actual object attribute name.